# CheckBox Enable

Tags: android, checkbox

i have a problem and i dont know how to fix it .I want to make a basic begginer calculator app.I want  only one checkbox to be checkable at time but i cant figure out ,stil can check all .And how can i cast strings from edittext to doubl?.App is not finished yet .
Sorry for english.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.top_fragment);

     double result ;

    EditText number_1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_1);
    EditText number_2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_2);
    CheckBox add_box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.add_box);
    CheckBox subtract_box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.subtract_box);
    CheckBox divide_box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.divide_box);
    CheckBox product_box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.product_box);
    final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

   number_1.getText().toString();
   number_2.getText().toString();

    if(add_box.isChecked())
    {
        subtract_box.setEnabled(false);
        divide_box.setEnabled(false);
        product_box.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(subtract_box.isChecked())
    {
        product_box.setEnabled(false);
        divide_box.setEnabled(false);
        add_box.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(divide_box.isChecked())
    {
        subtract_box.setEnabled(false);
        product_box.setEnabled(false);
        add_box.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(product_box.isChecked())
    {
        subtract_box.setEnabled(false);
        divide_box.setEnabled(false);
        add_box.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a listener.

```
add_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
            Disable or enable what you want here. it will be called when add_box is checked or unchecked.

            }
        });
```

Do the same for each checkbox, disabling or enabling what you want.

To convert to String to Double you can do that:

```
Double value1 = Double.valueOf(number_1.getText().toString());
```

Make sure its not a null value and can be cast to a double. 
You can use try / catch.

Answer (score 0):

You may use RadioButton and RadioGroup instead of Checkboxes.

Radio buttons allow the user **to select one option** from a set. You should use radio buttons for optional sets that are **mutually exclusive**.

Official doc of RadioButton:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

**Update:**

To convert a String to Double you can do that:

```
// obtain a reference
EditText number_1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_1);
// obtain the string value
String number_1String = number_1.getText().toString()
// convert the string value to double value
Double number_1Double = Double.valueOf(number_1String);
```